# Unstack two columns at the same time to produce a concatenated columnname

Tags: python, pandas, multi-level

I have a grouped dataframe that looks like:

```
Date         ID        Name       Category     Group        Amount
2018-02-28   123       ABC         Fruits      INT           22345
2018-02-28   456       JFGT        Veg         FEE           56789
2018-02-28   5687      AST         Seeds       FEE           4567
2018-02-28   5687      AST         Seeds       INT           236
.............
.............
2018-03-31   123       ABC         Fruits      INT           790
2018-03-31   456       JFGT        Veg         FEE           35637
2018-03-31   5687      AST         Seeds       FEE           4567
2018-03-31   5687      AST         Seeds       INT           236
.............
.............
```

I need to essentially unstack the amounts by Group and Date column to create something like:

```
ID      Name     Category   INT_2018-02  INT_2018-03   FEE_2018-02  FEE_2018-03
123      ABC         Fruits     22345        790       
456      JFGT        Veg                                   56789  35637 
5687     AST         Seeds                                 4567    4567
5687     AST         Seeds      236      236
.............
.............
```

It is essentially an unstack.
I can do a normal unstack of the Group by

```
 df = df.set_index(['Date','ID','Name','Category','Group'])['Amount'].unstack().reset_index()
```

However, Am not sure how I can use the Date or use two columns for the unstack method.
Please advise.

Comment: How about concatenating `Group` and `Date`, making the new column the index, and unstacking?

Comment: Thats a good option, Why did I not think of it :)

Comment: Actually, you need to pivot, not to unstack. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new column:

```
df["GD"] = df["Group"] + "_" + df["Date"]
```

Pivot the DF around the new column:

```
result = df[["ID", "Name", "Category"]]\
        .join(df.pivot(None, "GD", "Amount"))\
        .fillna(" ") # The last line is not necessary
#     ID  Name Category FEE_2018-02-28 INT_2018-02-28
#0   123   ABC   Fruits                         22345
#1   456  JFGT      Veg          56789               
#2  5687   AST    Seeds           4567               
#3  5687   AST    Seeds                           236
```

Comment: Unstack gives me the same thing. Am i missing something here ?

Comment: unstack should give you a column MultiIndex. If you are ok with this, use unstack.